# If I replace an element from within that element, is the remaining JavaScript guaranteed to run?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Example:

```
...
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.body.innerHTML = 'foo';
        alert('bar');
    </script>
</body>
...
```

Is this guaranteed to alert "bar"? Or could that get skipped depending on how fast the innerHTML gets replaced?

Answer (score 2):

It should still alert "bar". The script has already been loaded, and removing the script tag that allowed it to be loaded doesn't change anything.

To test it: place your alert inside a setTimeout.